# Minimum voltage supply for a MOSFET-based ring oscillator

Tags: transistors, mosfet, oscillator

I am trying to build a ring oscillator based on N-channel MOSFET like below:

[image: oscillator schematic]

How to compute the minimum \$V_{DD}\$ required for the circuit to oscillate? Is this the gate threshold voltage (\$V_{GS(th)}\$) + the voltage drop from the \$R_D\$ resistor?

My goal is to have a \$V_{DD}\$ of 3.3V to interface this circuit directly to a microcontroller.

Comment: Vdd min depends on Vt

Comment: You need to define Rd , gm, Vt but Vdd = 1.3x Vt is possible with R=1k so 3.3V is easy.

Comment: You could simulate this circuit in the free tool LTspice. Like Tony suggests, you need a Vt of 2.5V or lower, so, look for a "logic level mosfet".